# Why Object converted using Array.from method shows the array as typeof object?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object, dom

I created a `HTMLCollection` by using the method `document.getElementsByClassName` and I know that it returns an Object. But when I converted that object into Array using the `Array.from` method and then checked its type, it still shows the type as of `Object`.
While I'm able to perform the array operations upon the same.

Why is it so?
[image]

Comment: Arrays **are** objects.  Even if you do `typeof []` you'll get the same result.  If you want to test whether an array is an array instead of any other data type, then use `Array.isArray()`.